# Class inheritance is not working for subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
    namespace Littler_story 
    {
        class Profession
         {
            public int Strength
             { public get; public set { if ((Strength + value) > Strength) { 
             Strength = value; } } }
            public int Intelligence
             { public get; public set { if ((Intelligence + value) > 
             Intelligence) { Intelligence = value; } } }
            public int Agility
             { public get; public set { if ((Agility + value) > Strength) { 
             Strength = value; } } }
            public int Charisma
             { public get; public set { if ((Charisma + value) > Charisma) { 
             Charisma = value; } } }
            public int Health
             { public get; public set { if ((Health + value) <= 0) { 
             Console.WriteLine("Game over!"); } } }
    }
        class FireFighter : Profession
        {
            Strength = 5;
            Intelligence = 2;
            Agility = 3;
            Charisma = 3;
            Health = 100;
        }
```

I'm getting errors for all of my attributes within the Firefighter class. I originally defined all of the variables as local variables within each class. I recently learned inheritance and since all five of my profession classes share the same attributes I figured I could create a superclass for all of them. As you can see they are defined within Profession but putting them in one of my classes (Firefighter) causes an error. An error that will likely span across all my classes if I implement it. I'm guessing it might be the way I've made my automatic properties within the Profession class? The error I'm getting is that those attributes strength, agility, endurance etc. do not exist in the current context.

Comment: You need to define the value of the properties in the `FireFighter` constructor

Comment: Always a pleasure to find fellow developers who find serious issues with the language :-D

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good fit for inheritance; `FireFighter` should probably just be an instance of `Profession` rather than a subtype.

Comment: Those property definitions won't even [compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/86TzXw). Forget the `FireFighter` class entirely and focus on understanding properties first.

Comment: Side note: if you looking to enforce values of property to always be positive it is more readable to write `if (value > 0)` than `if (value + Str > Str)`... and consider to throw exception if value is negative (and maybe 0).

Comment: Thanks you all! @AlexeiLevenkov I was actually planning on making it to where the value set would always be higher than the original value. For example, it's an interactive story where a user can make choices. Based on those choices they can gain additional attribute points to these fields. I wanted to make it to where the values always incremented. For example, they gain +2 strength so the value already being 6 would be 8. Once they're gained they're never lost. Is this solution still good for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant just set properties that way. You need to access them within a constructor and or by instantiating the class then setting the inherited property.

so a way to do this would be :

```
FireFighter f = new FireFighter ();
f.Strength = 5;
```

or in a construtor method :

```
public class FireFighter : Profession
 {
  public FireFighter()
  {
    Strength = 5;
  }
 }
```

Comment: A better answer would have been showing the code using the constructor rather then instantiating (probably with surrounding class code just to clarify how it supposed to look for completeness)

Comment: That's not how you declare a constructor.

Comment: please remove ```void``` to make it a constructor

Comment: haha typo remove it thanks! :)

Comment: So based on this answer I guess inheritance really isn't a good fit for this. I figured inheritance would do what a constructor does without having to create new constructors for each class in this case. Maybe my understanding was wrong which annoys me because I've progressed this far in Codecademy and it's been telling me my way of thinking in solving its problems were correct. Thank you all, back to the drawing board! :(